# JFileChooser - Starting at the 'Computer' e.g. C: D: E: drives

Tags: java, windows-7, jfilechooser

I'm trying to add the finishing touches to an application I've been developing and I'd really like it so my fileChooser sets the current directory as the area in which you can select which drive to start from. I've looked at the Windows 7 path for this area and it seems to just be called 'Computer'. I've tried entering this into the space where "C:\" is in the below code but that doesn't work.

```
fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("C:\\"));
```

Does anyone know what you would enter to have it so the user first selects which drive to open from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the problem is that what is called "Computer" in Windows, is not really a folder, just behaves like one. It's just a special way Windows use to display the most common folders (like C:, D:, Documents etc.), just to make the user's life easier.
I'm not sure how you can achieve what you want, but i think this might help you:
[link](http://en.allexperts.com/q/Windows-XP-3282/path-Computer.htm)

Comment: Cheers, I appreciate it. I suppose it makes sense and I actually sort of knew about the 'My Computer' thing. Seems like they should create a kind of path for it. Anyway, appreciate it :D Just have to mention this in my evaluation now!

Comment: you could also try "%systemroot%\explorer.exe /e,::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}" instead of "C:\". Not sure if it works in windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me under Windows XP:

```
     file_open_dialog = new JFileChooser();
     try {
        File dummy_file = new File(new File("C:\\").getCanonicalPath());
        file_open_dialog.setCurrentDirectory(dummy_file);
        file_open_dialog.changeToParentDirectory();
     } catch (IOException system_event) {
        ;
     };
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you need to put.  But if you can browse in the file chooser to the location you want, select a file and in Java printout the path.  That should give you want you need to know.